# inheriting friend operators in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, operators

So I have class A and class B, where class B extends class A. I must overload the << and >> in both classes. I was hoping that in the function definition of the operators for class B, I could call the overloaded operators from class A, but I'm having trouble doing so.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A {
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, A a);
protected:
    int i;
    string st;
public:
    A(){
        i=50;
        st = "boop1";
    }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, A a) {
out << a.i << a.st;
return out;
}

class B : public A {
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, B b);
private:
    int r;
public:
    B() : A() {
        r=12;
    }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, B b) {
out = A::operator<<(out, b);    //operator<< is not a member of A
out << "boop2" << b.r;
return out;
}

int main () {
B b;
cout << b;
}
```

I attempt to call A's version of operator<< in B's version of operator<<, but of course it doesn't actually belong to A, so it cannot compile. How should I be achieving this?

also, note that in reality A and B have their own header and body files.

Comment: Have you considered making the operator overload a member of A?

Comment: @Borgleader: you can't make operator << a member of A because A appears on the right side of the operator, not the left. It must either be a standalone function or a friend function.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: since the answers got fixed, I removed my comment (and I knew that it would be wrong ;)

Comment: @bstamour: Ohhhhh you're right -.-;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your `B` object look like an `A` object:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, B const& b) {
    out << static_cast<A const&>(b);
    out << "boop2" << b.r;
    return out;
}
```

Note that you almost certainly don't want to pass the object to be printed by value. I have changed the signature to use a `const&` instead: This indicates that the object won't get changed and it won't get copied.

Comment: I should have asked this hours ago but... how would i do the same thing with a operator>> ?

Comment: Well, for input you want to use a non-const reference, i.e., the cast would be `static_cast<A&>(b)`.

Answer (score 2):

`A`'s `operator<<` is indeed *not* a member of `A`, but rather is in namespace scope. The correct approach here is to use type coercion to let overload resolution do the right thing. Change:

```
out = A::operator<<(out, b);
```

to:

```
out << static_cast<A>(b);
```

Also, you should change your operators to take the second argument by `const&`, in which case it should be the following in order to avoid an extra copy:

```
out << static_cast<A const&>(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

They are global functions, don't qualify them with the scope-resolution operator:

```
operator<<(out, static_cast<const A&>(b)) << "boop2" << b.r;
```

You have to cast it so you don't call the function you're in and get infinite recursion. Also, don't assign the result of `operator<<` to `out`; it won't work and it's not what you want to do.

Also your functions should accept `const A&`'s and `const B&`'s (that is, you should accept the paramters by `const` reference, not value) to prevent unnecessary copying.